# Get IIS Settings from non-ASP program

Tags: c#, iis, wix

I want to read some IIS settings in my installer custom action.

Is there easy access to the IIS settings available; or can I read them from the Registry somehow?

Namely, the settings I need right now are:

- Does a Default Web Site exist?
- If so, what hostnames/ports is it bound to?
- Does the server have an SSL certificate configured?
- If so, is SSL enforced for the Default Web Site?

How can I get this information from my application?

Comment: There are both COM & WMI interfaces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526050(v=vs.90).aspx I found WMI a bit friendlier.